# Copy code from Postman to Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, postman, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using a postman software to test the API response.

I'm getting a proper response with the following URL:

http://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_0e5804165231asdfe89dc8a7c0b4e1d3260&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1475703426&oauth_nonce=QoQ9e3QvCTI&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=TdRs2XsVzdIu4fLoiW8gMWj56VpzrDLZS6mOJ18ZQzc%3DGet

So i went to the code option in postman app, it gives me complete code for this request in objective(NSURL).

But when i copy paste that code in my app and check for the response. it returns 401 server code.

Can someone please guide me a right direction to make it work.

Comment: Please post your code @Jimmy

Comment: I am having same issue.did you get any resolution?

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper yes, I figure out i need to create an auth_signature, timestamp and nonce in my code.

Comment: I am already doing that..but still having same issue. The API works fine in postman, but giving issues in Xcode.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper Hmm, does your api returns any error message? Mine was returning "Invalid signature" error.

Comment: yes it gives me this error:
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.","data":{"status":401}}
and in the NSError it says: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)"